# MIN/MAX VALUES GROUP BY ID

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

**Find the names and addresses of the customers with the highest balance and the people with the lowest loan in each branch.**

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE Branch(
BranchID INT NOT NULL,
           Address varchar(100),
           ManagerSsn varchar(100),
           Branch_name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (BranchID)
);


CREATE TABLE Has_Account(
Assn Int,
           ANo CHAR(16),
           Opened_date date,
    PRIMARY KEY(Assn),
FOREIGN KEY(Assn) REFERENCES Customer(Ssn),
FOREIGN KEY(ANo) REFERENCES Account(AccountNo)
);

CREATE TABLE Account(
           AccountNo CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
           BranchID Int,
           Balance Int,
    PRIMARY KEY(AccountNo),
    FOREIGN KEY(BranchID) REFERENCES Branch(BranchID)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer(
Ssn Int CHECK(0101000000000 < Ssn < 3112999995999) NOT NULL,
           Address VARCHAR(100),
           Name VARCHAR(100),
           EmployerID Int,
    PRIMARY KEY(Ssn) 
);

CREATE TABLE Loan(
LoanNo CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
BranchID Int,
           Amount Int,
    PRIMARY KEY(LoanNo),
    FOREIGN KEY(BranchID) REFERENCES Branch(BranchID)
);

CREATE TABLE Has_Loan(
LNo CHAR(16),
Lssn Int,
Repay_date date,
PRIMARY KEY (LNo),
FOREIGN KEY(Lno) REFERENCES Loan(LoanNo),
FOREIGN KEY(Lssn) REFERENCES Customer(Ssn)
);
```

**Populating the tables**

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES('2004980890999', ‘Kanaribakken 2B’, ‘Paul Stolten’, ‘’);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES(‘1010968250234’, ‘Parkveien 5’, ‘Anders Nilsson’, ‘’, );

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES(‘2104996495987’, ‘Kongeveien 24B’, ‘Karoline Torskerud’, ‘123’, );

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES(‘2910943135444’, ‘Gåsesmauet 3’, ‘Bente Arildsen’, ‘555’, );

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES(‘1304980890678’, ‘Knallebakken 30’, ‘Knut Solberg’, ‘555’,);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES('1019730000234', ‘Laksebakken 40’, ‘Harald Olsen’, ‘’);

INSERT INTO BRANCH
VALUES (‘123’, ‘Børsveien 49’, ‘1412963670786’, ‘Nesttun’,);

INSERT INTO BRANCH
VALUES(‘555’, ‘Vimpelveien 24’, ‘2412983905999’, ‘DNB’,);

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT
VALUES (‘1234567890087620’, ‘123’, ‘459’,);

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT
VALUES (‘8402849284910340’, ‘123’, ‘35120’,);

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT
VALUES (‘3452948293817280’, ‘555’, ‘69’,);

INSERT INTO HAS_ACCOUNT
VALUES(‘1010968250234’, ‘1234567890087620’, ‘17.04.2012’,);

INSERT INTO HAS_ACCOUNT
VALUES (‘2104996495987’, ‘8402849284910340’, ‘20.09.2000’,);

INSERT INTO HAS_ACCOUNT
VALUES (‘2910943135444’, ‘3452948293817280’, ‘29.01.2006’,);

INSERT INTO LOAN
VALUES (‘2291928394039280’, ‘555’, ‘50000’,);

INSERT INTO LOAN 
VALUES (‘1295829384932100’, ‘123’, ‘400000’,);

INSERT INTO LOAN 
VALUES ('1295829384932222', ‘123’, ‘40000’);

INSERT INTO HAS_LOAN
VALUES (‘2910943135444’, ‘2291928394039280’, ‘09.09.2019’,);

INSERT INTO HAS_LOAN
VALUES (‘2104996495987’, ‘1295829384932100’, ‘14.03.2022’,);

INSERT INTO HAS_LOAN
VALUES ('2004980890999', '1295829384932222', '01.02.2021');
```

**Draft so far:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer.Name, Customer.Address
FROM Customer, Account, Loan, Has_Account, Has_Loan
WHERE Customer.Ssn = Has_Account.Assn AND Has_Account.Assn = Has_Loan.Lssn 
    (SELECT Account.Balance MAX(Balance) GROUP BY(BranchID)) AND 
    Loan.AMOUNT(SELECT Loan.Amount MIN(Amount) GROUP BY(BranchID));
```

I think it is correct that we need to group our output by BranchID, and max/min is ok. Looks like the statement formalities are wrong somehow. 
Any help or hint is much appreciated!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Better use explicit join syntax like @jarlh said. Start now in learning this and you'll save yourself infinite debug headache and infinite hatred from your fellow coders who have to maintain this.

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code posted.  1st, there are extra commas in the Insert statements at the end. 2nd the datatypes are wrong for the insert- you put strings in there (values surrounded by apostrophes '') when they are supposed to be ints. When SQL attemtps to cast these strings to integers some of the values are greater the max range of an int.  You also use the different style of apostrophes ‘ ’ when it is ' ' that are compatible with SQL code.  In any case, values out of range of the datatype specified means your question can never be answered.